# Google Adwords Conversion Tracking: How to decide myself if it was a conversion

Tags: google-ads-api

Google Adwords optimizes the number of Conversions, but different Conversions can have a different quality.
In my case I defined submitting a form as a conversion. The number of conversions grew in the last couple of days, but the quality (which I subjectively decide based on what the users filled out) decreased.

Is there a way, to save the Tracking Id of a user and to somehow decide myself if this was a Conversion or not? Or probably even better let me decide the quality of the Conversion?

Answer (score 1):

I'd imagine adding a hidden input to the form (ie. timestamp + session id) and passing that same value to a custom variable. At least that way you could match visitor data to a converting user.

Concerning quality; you could add events to filled out textareas, input fields and/or selected/checked inputs, which would fire on submit. The custom variable with most events would have the highest quality. Though I'm not quite sure if you'd be able to abuse events in such a way, you should run some tests.

edit: this all of course depends on whether you use analytics to track your adwords traffic.

Comment: Using JS you might also be able to load different conversion scripts after a input field has been selected/checked/filled out/etc.